# Heroku "free quota exhausted" even after transfer to a new account

Tags: heroku, web-hosting, heroku-cli

I had my developer account, where app used all free quota. After that I transferred it to business account.

But Heroku didn't started to use time from it. And still I see this error in logs:

`code=H82 desc="Free app running time quota exhausted"`

I tried to restart dyno, but it didn't help. Documentation doesn't have any information about that.

Comment: What do you mean with "developer" and "business" account? There are only unverified and verified accounts. With both accounts you can still exhaust your quota. You can buy upgraded Dynos on a per Application basis. Your app is still running on the free app tier.

Comment: @TinNguyen business account doesn't have any usage of free quota. And app fails to start or make a new build. If I create new app on business account - it works well.

Comment: Please provide a source for that infromation. I find nothing when I google "heroku business account dyno hours"

Comment: @TinNguyen, ok let's call it acccount1 and account2 for clarity instead of developer and business :)

Comment: You can't circumvent the dyno hour usage limit by transferring the application to another account.

Comment: @TinNguyen but that app used only 20 hours, and others used the rest. Now I want to provide it to real owner.

Comment: You can deploy a new application.

Comment: @TinNguyen but it has a lot of configuration, DNS, database and other plugins

Comment: Wait until the new month. And make sure on the new month he has enough free hours https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing

Comment: @TinNguyen, thanks. But this is not an option as web app needs to work today.

Comment: How did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: @TinNguyen created new app to use it till the end of month and shared all resources for it. Also needed to reconfigure DNS. But this temporary for this month. Haven’t found solution to start using new account immediately. Hope that from new month issue will be fixed and will back to old app.

Answer (score 2):

Used free dyno hours are non-transferable. If you transfer an application that has used hours to a different account, the portion you used while the app was on your account will remain until it resets the following month.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool

Comment: But even if I have more free hours on another account - it still don't work.